# AWS ec2 increasing load handling

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have code that uses a GET command from the Python REQUESTS library to pull data from an API. I am expecting, for example, 10 large files to be sent to me.

Can someone help explain to me how my code should be written where I can take 1 file and analyze it and then take another file in parallel to analyze that and so on? Is it possible to analyze all 10 at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not really a question about AWS and EC2.

Assuming that you don't want to rewrite your code too significantly, you may want to concurrently run many instances of your Python program, each with a different input file as the argument.

Assuming a typical workflow is:

```
python blah.py inputfile.xyz
```

You could now run something like:

```
python blah.py inputfile1.xyz &
python blah.py inputfile2.xyz &
...
python blah.py inputfileN.xyz &
wait
```

Note: this is the lazy way out. Optimal solutions will require rewriting code to be multithreaded, and analyzing your various resource limits.

The number of processes that you run should be limited by the number of vCPUs provided by your EC2 instance.

You may also be limited by your network bandwidth, in terms of multiple parallel downloads. Finally, some EC2 instances have burst limits after which they perform noticeably poorly.

Comment: Thank you for your response as this is a great guide for me to revise my approach. What type of question would this be considered? I assumed AWS and EC2 because that is the platform I am working on.

Comment: So each line of code executing "python blah.py &" uses 1 process? If not, how can I check how many processes it uses?

Comment: Yes, it does. Read about this here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line ; you can count the running processes using `ps`

Comment: So if i have 1 vCPU does that mean I can only run 1 command at a time? I am using the t2.micro instance.

Comment: Yes, doing any of this on a t2.micro is probably overkill, not really because of the vCPUs but also the low network bandwidth and burst-based usage. You cannot run stable, long-running resource-intensive applications on a t2.micro.